# Add quotation marks to string between numbers

Tags: javascript, split

I'm trying to convert a string to an array, however I'm having a bit of trouble.
A shortened example of the string -

```
"1 Afghanistan,2 Albania,3 Algeria,4 American Samoa,5 Andorra,6 Angola,7 Anguilla,8 Antarctica,9 Antigua and Barbuda,10 Argentina,11 Armenia,12 Aruba,208 Tanzania, United Republic of,209 Thailand"
```

The issue here is that, I want to split it by the commas, however certain elements seem to be using commas as well, like `208 Tanzania, United Republic of` should be kept as it is.

So can I split it between the numbers instead of by `.split(',')`

Comment: May you show us the code you have already tried? See [mcve].

Comment: How do you intend to tell the difference between the "good" commas and the "bad" commas?

Comment: @Liam the *good* commas are followed by a number

Comment: You can't really be sure of this @Cid. OP needs to confirm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can match all the commas only followed by numbers using RegEx ***Positive Lookahead***:

```js
var countries = "1 Afghanistan,2 Albania,3 Algeria,4 American Samoa,5 Andorra,6 Angola,7 Anguilla,8 Antarctica,9 Antigua and Barbuda,10 Argentina,11 Armenia,12 Aruba,208 Tanzania, United Republic of,209 Thailand";

countries = countries.split(/,(?=\d+)/)
console.log(countries);
```